# Excel - Find the Max for Total revenue just for year 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can not figure out the correct formula to find the MAX of Total Revenue(E) for Year 1(B) only.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

I've tried
=MAX(MATCH(1,(I14=Yrs)*(E2:E308),0))
=INDEX(E2:E308,MATCH(1,(E2:E308)*(Year_1=C2:C308),0))

And a few others

[nyse data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NUfc.png)

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541). Can you please fix the formatting of your code? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Office365 and LibreOffice Calc, there is the [MAXIFS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883). In the example you provided, formula that calculates maximal revenue in "Year 1":

```
=MAXIFS(E2:E308,C2:C308,"Year 1")
```

In Excel 2016, the problem can be solved by combining MAX and IF in an array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(C2:C308="Year 1",E2:E308))
```

(Don't forget to use `CTRL+SHIFT+Enter` to confirm.)